# Notify (RX) data observer only when table size changed

Tags: android, objectbox

I am using reactive observers (RxJava2) for listening DB changes.

Here is subscription method:

```
  fun subscribeGetTasks(): Flowable<List<Task>> {
        val query = taskBox.query().build()
        return RxQuery.observable(query).toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
    }
```

However, I would like be only notified when table size changed.
How to achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no special feature for that. Your observer would have to call `count()`  on the box if you have no query conditions (otherwise there would also be a `count()` on the Query object).

However, better not use a Query if you are only interested in the count for all objects in a box. Instead, you can do this with ObjectBox:

```
DataObserver<Class<Task>> taskObserver = new DataObserver<Class<Task>>() {
    @Override public void onData(Class<Note> data) {
        long taskCount = taskBox.count();
    }
};
boxStore.subscribe(Task.class).observer(taskObserver);
```

For additional reading, please check the [docs](https://docs.objectbox.io/data-observers-and-rx#observing-general-changes).